# How can we remove the "Copy Link Requires Adobe Flash Player" link from the OBIEE12c analytical report?

Tags: oracle, obiee

We configure "instanceconfig.xml" file to remove the Adobe flash player dependency to show the charts and graphs in the obiee12c analytical reports and dashboards. Now, OBIEE12c can display charts without the Adobe Flash Player, However, reports still shows a link named "Copy Link Requires Adobe Flash Player"

Answer (score 0):

a) "12c" doesn't mean anything as there were 5 major releases with over 50 bundle patches

b) This is fixed since 2016 and clearly explained in support document 2111430.1:
https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=2111430.1